# GTM event parameter for GA4 ecommerce purchase on Magento

Tags: magento2, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I'm trying to setup GA4 ecommerce purchase via GTM, on my Magento ecommerce site. I have setup the ecommerce datalayer variables accordingly, but GA4 doesn't seem to capture the items purchased. Example, I have configured the below parameters:

- value mapped to ecommerce.purchase.actionField.revenue
- transaction_id mapped to ecommerce.purchase.actionField.id
- currency mapped to ecommerce.currencyCode
- items mapped to ecommerce.items

Would need help on this, thanks.

Comment: I have the same issue, it looks like no currency is send in the purchase event.

Comment: please provide code what you tried then only people will able to help you here